# How to speed up this big additive for loop in Python with Numba?

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to speed up this function, which takes an array D of size (M,N,O), an array Pi of size (M,M) and arrays x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi of size (M,N,O) as inputs, and returns an array D_new of similar size.

```
@njit
def forward_policy_2d_njit(D, Pi, x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi):
    nZ, nX, nY = D.shape
    Dnew = np.zeros_like(D)

    for iz_next in range(nZ):
        for iz in range(nZ):
            for ix in range(nX):
                for iy in range(nY):
                    ixp = x_i[iz, ix, iy]
                    iyp = y_i[iz, ix, iy]
                    beta = x_pi[iz, ix, iy]
                    alpha = y_pi[iz, ix, iy]

                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp, iyp] += alpha * beta * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp+1, iyp] += alpha * (1 - beta) * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp, iyp+1] += (1 - alpha) * beta * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp+1, iyp+1] += (1 - alpha) * (1 - beta) * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
    return Dnew
```

I have tried to `@guvectorize` it, but it does not give back the proper result. Do you know how I could speed it up, or make good use of guvectorize?

Edit: after the comment of Jérôme Richard, I add a running example of the code. The matrix Dnew should sum to approximatively 1 in all cases.

```
from numba import njit, guvectorize
import numpy as np 

nA = 60
nB = 40
nZ = 3

Pi = np.array([
    [0.5,0.5,0],
    [0,0.5,0.5],
    [0.5,0,0.5]
])

D = np.ones((nZ,nB,nA)) / (nZ*nB*nA)

x_pi = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high = 1, size = (nZ, nB, nA))
y_pi = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high = 1, size = (nZ, nB, nA))

x_i = np.random.randint(0, nB-1, (nZ, nB, nA))
y_i = np.random.randint(0, nA-1, (nZ, nB, nA))


@njit
def forward_policy_2d_njit(D, Pi, x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi):
    nZ, nX, nY = D.shape
    Dnew = np.zeros_like(D)

    for iz_next in range(nZ):
        for iz in range(nZ):
            for ix in range(nX):
                for iy in range(nY):
                    ixp = x_i[iz, ix, iy]
                    iyp = y_i[iz, ix, iy]
                    beta = x_pi[iz, ix, iy]
                    alpha = y_pi[iz, ix, iy]

                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp, iyp] += alpha * beta * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp+1, iyp] += alpha * (1 - beta) * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp, iyp+1] += (1 - alpha) * beta * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp+1, iyp+1] += (1 - alpha) * (1 - beta) * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
    return Dnew

@guvectorize(['void(float64[:,:,:], float64[:,:], int64[:,:,:], int64[:,:,:], float64[:,:,:], float64[:,:,:], float64[:,:,:])'], '(i,j,k),(i,i),(i,j,k),(i,j,k),(i,j,k),(i,j,k)->(i,j,k)')
def forward_policy_2d_vec(D, Pi, x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi, Dnew):
    nZ, nX, nY = D.shape
    Dnew = np.zeros_like(D)

    for iz_next in range(nZ):
        for iz in range(nZ):
            for ix in range(nX):
                for iy in range(nY):
                    ixp = x_i[iz, ix, iy]
                    iyp = y_i[iz, ix, iy]
                    beta = x_pi[iz, ix, iy]
                    alpha = y_pi[iz, ix, iy]

                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp, iyp] += alpha * beta * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp+1, iyp] += alpha * (1 - beta) * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp, iyp+1] += (1 - alpha) * beta * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    Dnew[iz_next, ixp+1, iyp+1] += (1 - alpha) * (1 - beta) * Pi[iz, iz_next] * D[iz, ix, iy]
                    
Dnew_jit = forward_policy_2d_njit(D, Pi, x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi)
Dnew_vec = forward_policy_2d_vec(D, Pi, x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi)

print(np.sum(Dnew_jit)) # Check: Dnew should be equal to 1
print(np.sum(Dnew_vec)) # Check: Dnew should be equal to 1
```

Comment: What is the actual *real-world* size of each array? Ideally, can you give a complete example with such arrays (possibly initialized with random values)?

Comment: You are completely right, sorry about that. I will edit my question with a working example. The 3D matrices are typically 3x40x60.

Comment: Are you open to using something other than numba, like numpy?

Comment: Learn C++ and save yourself the headache of numba and other such wrappers.  I feel like you're me, from 2 years ago.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am of course, but the function needs to be jit-able.

to alvrm: That would of course be a possibility, but right now, I'm going to stay with python.

Comment: If you want speed, use C or Fortran, or maybe something like Julia. Numba is a rather pointless level of complexity, as @alvrm correctly points out

Comment: The numpy solutions I have in mind likely won't be jittable, but you also won't need to

Comment: There is no reason to believe C/C++ or Julia will be faster than Numba for this specific code. This is especially true for Julia that makes use of the same LLVM JIT compiler toolchain than Numba. C/C++ might slightly be faster for the indexing (due to negative indices of Numpy), but it does not seems to be the bottleneck here anyway. In fact, negative values might need to be supported in this code regarding the OP need and the content of the input arrays like `x_i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to optimize this code. Indeed, the arrays are too small for a multithreading to be efficient, the accesses are mainly not contiguous so SIMD vectorization is not easily nor efficient. That being said, we can move the `iz_next` loop so to **factorize operations**, that is, not recomputing things nor reading the same array multiple times. Moreover, we can **tell to the compiler that `nZ` is 3** using assertions so it can generate a faster code thanks to *loop unrolling*. If this is not always the case, you can write different functions with different assertions. The main code can be shared in another Numba function without impacting performance as long as the inner function is inlined (using the flag `inline=always"`). We can also tell to the compiler that arrays are contiguous in practice so to avoid additional indexing instructions being generated.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
@njit(['(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,::1], int32[:,:,::1], int32[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1])',
    '(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,::1], int64[:,:,::1], int64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1])'])
def forward_policy_2d_njit_opt(D, Pi, x_i, y_i, x_pi, y_pi):
    nZ, nX, nY = D.shape
    assert nZ == 3 
    Dnew = np.zeros_like(D)

    for iz in range(nZ):
        for ix in range(nX):
            for iy in range(nY):
                ixp = x_i[iz, ix, iy]
                iyp = y_i[iz, ix, iy]
                beta = x_pi[iz, ix, iy]
                alpha = y_pi[iz, ix, iy]
                D_value = D[iz, ix, iy]
                tmp_1 = alpha * beta * D_value
                tmp_2 = alpha * (1 - beta) * D_value
                tmp_3 = (1 - alpha) * beta * D_value
                tmp_4 = (1 - alpha) * (1 - beta) * D_value
                tmp_view_1 = Dnew[:, ixp, iyp]
                tmp_view_2 = Dnew[:, ixp+1, iyp]
                tmp_view_3 = Dnew[:, ixp, iyp+1]
                tmp_view_4 = Dnew[:, ixp+1, iyp+1]

                for iz_next in range(nZ):
                    Pi_value = Pi[iz, iz_next]
                    tmp_view_1[iz_next] += tmp_1 * Pi_value
                    tmp_view_2[iz_next] += tmp_2 * Pi_value
                    tmp_view_3[iz_next] += tmp_3 * Pi_value
                    tmp_view_4[iz_next] += tmp_4 * Pi_value
    return Dnew
```

This code is **twice faster** on my machine. It takes about 65 µs on the provided input array.

The loop can theoretically be slightly vectorized using SIMD instructions (along the `iz_next` axis) but Numba fail to do that, even when `Dnew` is transposed. In fact, this is apparently due to LLVM-JIT and more specifically to LLVM. Using a C/C++ code should not help (at least, not using Clang and probably not other compilers like GCC nor MSVC), unless you write C/C++ code using low-level SIMD intrinsics which is tedious, non-portable (dependent of the processor instruction set) and bug-prone. Moreover, one need to consider the overhead of transposing `Dnew` in the end. I expect this to be a bit faster but I am not sure it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It's very helpful. Could you give some explanation why you didn't use guvectorize? Do you think a faster solution could be possible using it?

Comment: I do not think guvectorize can be faster in this case. The code cannot be trivially vectorize as it is unless AVX-512 is available, but even in this case, the result will certainly be disappointing. Moreover, I tends to prefer a manual approach since it is generally easier to optimize a code with basic loops IMO and I find guvectorize quite tedious to use in practice (and less readable than basic loops). AFAIK, guvectorize is particularly useful mainly when you operate on arrays with a variable dimensions and want Numba to automatically add loops.